# Create html5 interactive plot (plotly) from R using ggplot2 with facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, plotly, ggplotly

I can convert a plot created by `ggplot2` easily via `plotly::ggplotly()` as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(as_tibble(iris), aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Length, color=Species)) + geom_point()
plotly::ggplotly()
```

[image]

I expected the following to work such that the points show up in each facets of the plotly figure.

```
ggplot(as_tibble(iris), aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Petal.Length)) + facet_wrap(~Species)+ geom_point()
plotly::ggplotly()
```

This `ggplot2` plot:

[image]

is converted to:

[image]

So it doesn't work, and simply returns a correctly faceted axes with no points.

Is there a workaround?

Versions:

```
R 3.6.1 
RStudio 1.2.1335
tidyverse 1.2.1
ggplot2 3.2.1
tibble  2.0.1
plotly 4.9.0
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Maybe try restart R?

Comment: Tried. Maybe due to some version mismatch between packages? I included some relevant version numbers.